# Ising model approximation of partition sum

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

If we consider the Ising model without magnetic field and without periodic boundary conditions we get for the partition sum $Z_N=2(2\cosh(K))^{N-1}$ ($K$ is dimensionless coupling). Why can we then say that $Z_N\approx(2\cosh(K))^{N} $ for large $N$? For me its like we would approximate $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}$ as $1$ (when $K$ is large). Is it because we always take the logarithm of the partition sum for physical quantities like the free energy?

Comment: In which context have you seen this claim? In which source? This information is required to answer your question.

Comment: @YvanVelenik https://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~biophys/PDF/Skripte/StatPhys.pdf on page 128.

Comment: Looking at the notes you linked to, it seems that indeed the author only does that to get a marginally simpler expression for the free energy (moreover, the free energy density, in the thermodynamic limit, would be unaffected by the change). It is quite pointless in my opinion. In fact, when he needs the partition function for his computation of the 2-point function on the next page, he uses once again the exact expression.

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you. So does that mean that this can only be justified because we are taking the logarithm and then in the TD limit it isn’t relevant that our partition sum could be several order of magnitudes higher?

Comment: Yes. (And in this particular case, the approximation seems useless to me.)